# Recursive table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion

I´m new to SQL so I´m sorry if I make some simple mistakes. Having said that, I wanted to create a recursive table but I´m not sure how.

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
employee_id INT NOT NULL ,
Bdate DATETIME,
address VARCHAR(80),
PRIMARY KEY(supervisor_number)
);
```

And I have a 1:N cardinality in which 1 supervisor can supervise N supervisees. That´s why i need a recursive table, because an employee can either be a supervisor or a supervisee.

I don´t know how to create the recursive table so if anyone knows how I would be extremely grateful!
If there´s anything that isn´t clear let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: *And I have a 1:N cardinality in which 1 supervisor can supervise N supervisees.* Does this means "1 supervisor can supervise from 0 to N supervisees" ? PS. Built-in data integrity system cannot check such constraint. External server-side checking (trigger) may solve. *I wanted to create a recursive table* This term not exists. You mean self-referenced table.

Comment: @Akina As I mentioned in the question 1 supervisor can supervise 1 to N supervisees. And thanks for the insight I will make to use that from now on

Answer (score 1):

create a table of relation , you can call it supervision;

it the new table , put 2 fields : supervisor and supervisee;
these two fields are foreign keys to the table Employee ;

for example, employee number 1 is a supervisor for the employee 2 and 3, you insert two lines in the new table :

```
insert into supervision (supervisor, supervisee) values (1, 2), (1, 3);
```

Comment: Is there a way of  doing it without creating a table of relation?

Comment: you can put the supervisor number as you did in the first reation ;

Answer (score 0):

Possible realization.

The table

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee(
employee_id INT NOT NULL ,
Bdate DATETIME,
address VARCHAR(80),
PRIMARY KEY(employee_id),
supervisor_id INT,
FOREIGN KEY (supervisor_id) REFERENCES employee(employee_id) 
        ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE );
```

The triggers which checks for subordinates amount (the value of 3 is hardcoded)

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_check_subordinates_amount
BEFORE INSERT
ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF 3 <= ( SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM employee
          WHERE supervisor_id = NEW.supervisor_id ) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No available slots for specified supervisor';
END IF;
END
```

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bu_check_subordinates_amount
BEFORE UPDATE
ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF 3 <= ( SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM employee
          WHERE supervisor_id = NEW.supervisor_id ) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No available slots for specified supervisor';
END IF;
END
```

[DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8765add3c351764ef5b69d3b8d5b9421)